# In "The Omen", what would have happened if someone killed Damien Thorn with something other than the seven daggers of Megiddo?

Tags: the-omen

It's said that the seven daggers of Megiddo are the only weapons that can kill the Antichrist. So what would have happened if someone shot Damien with a gun or beheaded him with a different weapon? Would he survive that?

Comment: Which "The Omen" are you referring to?

Comment: http://omen.wikia.com/wiki/Daggers_of_Megiddo

Comment: Predestination.  You can't kill him with bullets because its foretold that the daggers kill him.  If you try to use something else, you'll fail somehow.  The gun will jam, a pack of dogs will tear you to pieces, an aneurysm in your head will burst, etc.  You can't outwit the universe.